# How to detect if a string contains a HEX color code

Tags: javascript, regex, hex

I have this string:

```
3EFF3E[ADMIN] 99FF99User1 : test
```

I would like to know if there is any way to detect if the string actually contains a color or not. The color might be anywhere.

Comment: Please update the question to include the code you have already tried, along with a description of what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find if the string contains 6 hex digits in a row, you could use [`RegExp#test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
/[0-9A-F]{6}/i.test(str);
```

This will return a boolean value.

---

To actually find what the colors are, a simple way is to use [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), with a function:

```js
var str = '3EFF3E[ADMIN] 99FF99User1 : test';
var colors = [];

str.replace(/[0-9A-F]{6}/gi, function(color) {
  colors.push(color);
});

console.log(colors);
```

Or you could use the more traditional [`RegExp#exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) in a loop:

```js
var str = '3EFF3E[ADMIN] 99FF99User1 : test';
var colors = [];

var match, colorReg = /[0-9A-F]{6}/gi;
while ((match = colorReg.exec(str)) !== null) {
    colors.push(match[0]);
}

console.log(colors);
```